# find all keys in array which have this word in the value

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array $variants:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] =>
    [2] => MFG Part #
    [3] => Stock Status
    [4] => Capacity
    [5] => <img src="graphics/00000001/productimages/salter-brecknell-235-6m-11_xl.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    [6] => Brecknell
    [7] => 235
    [8] => In
    [9] => 11
    [10] => <img src="graphics/00000001/productimages/salter-brecknell-235-6m-22_xl.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    [11] => Brecknell
    [12] => 235
    [13] => In
    [14] => 22
    [15] => <img src="graphics/00000001/productimages/salter-brecknell-235-6m-56_xl.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    [16] => Brecknell 235-6M Hanging Scale-56 lb/25 kg Capacity
    [17] => 235
    [18] => In
    [19] => 56
    [20] => <img src="graphics/00000001/productimages/salter-brecknell-235-6m-220_xl.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    [21] => Brecknell
    [22] => 235
    [23] => In
    [24] => 220
)
```

I want to take all keys from this array that have in the value word **img**

and i did it like this:

```
            foreach($variants as $key_num=>$v){
                if (strpos($v, '<img') === 0) {
                    $key_array[] = $key_num;
                }

            }
            print_r($key_array);
```

and the result is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 14
    [3] => 19
)
```

But this is not good result, it should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 15
    [3] => 20
)
```

I have some other similar arryas, and this code works perfect but for this it doesnt work good, any help?

update:

```
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => '',
  2 => 'MFG Part #',
  3 => 'Stock Status',
  4 => 'Capacity',
  5 => '<img src="graphics/00000001/productimages/salter-brecknell-235-6m-11_xl.jpg" width="100" height="100">',
  6 => 'Brecknell',
  7 => '235',
  8 => 'In',
  9 => '11',
  10 => '<img src="graphics/00000001/productimages/salter-brecknell-235-6m-22_xl.jpg" width="100" height="100">',
  11 => 'Brecknell',
  12 => '235',
  13 => 'In',
  14 => '22',
  15 => '<img src="graphics/00000001/productimages/salter-brecknell-235-6m-56_xl.jpg" width="100" height="100">',
  16 => 'Brecknell',
  17 => '235',
  18 => 'In',
  19 => '56',
  20 => '<img src="graphics/00000001/productimages/salter-brecknell-235-6m-220_xl.jpg" width="100" height="100">',
  21 => 'Brecknell',
  22 => '235',
  23 => 'In',
  24 => '220',
)
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the outcome of `var_export($variants);`?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problems, I get 5, 10, 15, 20

Comment: @NigelRen its weird, i think this code is good, but wont work on my side

Comment: Different file/code being executed?

Comment: @NigelRen any ideas for doublechecking?

Comment: @Progrock i use the same file and code that i described in the description.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/kTQeF

Comment: @Rahul strange, do you know maybe what can cause this problem?

Comment: Try before your foreach, `$variants[0] = '<img test';` what's the output then?

Comment: @Progrock the same, just have key 0

Comment: Can you edit your post and instead of the array, paste the `json_encode($array)` instead? Then we can play with the code

Comment: You are not unsetting any values in the array or do some filtering like for example `$variants = array_values(array_unique($variants));` or 
`array_shift($variants);` etc.. ??

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes i founded error in my script, now works great

Answer (score -1):

In my script I had : `array_shift($variants);`

It was making the problem.